# Android class that contain a list of objects

Tags: java, android

I'm new with Android and Java.
I create a class that contain a list of materials and the user can add new materials from another `Dialog` activity.
When the user add a new material from the `Dialog` activity he loses the old material.
Obviously this happends because every time that the app call the activity receiver, the activity instantiates the class again (this is the problem?).
This is the code of the activity that receive data from the Dialog

```
package com.ddz.diarioscolastico;

import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivitySetOrario extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView textView;
DataBase DB = new DataBase();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_orario);
}//Fine oncreate

//Prende indietro la materia aggiunta dall'ActivityAddMateria
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            String result = data.getStringExtra("result");                
            Materia materia;
            materia = new Materia();
            materia.setMateria(result);
            materia.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.verde));
            DB.getMaterie().add(materia);

            LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contenitorematerie);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            params.setMargins(30, 0, 0, 0);

            for(int i=0; i< DB.getMaterie().size(); i++)
            {
                textView = new TextView(this);
                textView.setText(DB.getMaterie().get(i).getMateria());
                textView.setBackgroundColor(DB.getMaterie().get(i).getColor());
                textView.setLayoutParams(params);
                mLayout.addView(textView);
            }

        } 

        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Nessuna materia inserita
        }
    }
}//onActivityResult

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_set_orario, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.draw_orario:
        addMateria();
        return true;
    case R.id.save_data_orario:
        //SERIALIZZO I DATI CHE DOVRA PRENDERE ActivityOrario
        //FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        //os.writeObject(this);
        //os.close();
        //fos.close();
        backToOrario();
        return true;     
    case R.id.exit_orario:
        //Torno alla schermata orario annullo ogni modifica NON SERIALIZZO
        backToOrario();
        finish();
        return true;     
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

//Torna alla ActivityOrario
public void backToOrario(){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivitySetOrario.this, ActivityOrario.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}

public void addMateria(){
    //StartActivityForResult perchè mi aspetto la materia inserita dall'altra activity
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivitySetOrario.this, ActivityAddMateria.class);
    ActivitySetOrario.this.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
}
}
```

`DataBase DB = new DataBase();` every time call this new DataBase and I lose the old data!

Is this the problem?
I try to use a global variable, but I don't know where I need to instantiate the class only one time!

```
package com.ddz.diarioscolastico;

import android.app.Application;

class MyApp extends Application {

  public DataBase DB = new DataBase();

   public DataBase getState(){
     return DB;
   }
   public void setState(){
       DB = new DataBase();
   }
 }
```

Sorry for the bad english, if you need more explanations let me know!

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, you go to another activity and add items each time?

Comment: Yes, because the activity that receive the new materials is a table.
And the user  can drag and drop the materials added to the table.
It's a school diary.
It's a bad idea for you?
Thanks for your answere.

Comment: Just use static objects and you shall be fine!

Comment: @SNt so i need to write static DataBase DB = new DataBase(); and it's ok?

Comment: If you just want your DataBase object to stay the same as activities change, yes. but if you want the objects to stay the same, you can use a static ArrayList<T> to store your objects and then you are able to append new items to it without overwriting the old ones.

Comment: @SNt  i used the static to my declaration and now it's work! Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are welcome my friend

Answer (score 0):

You can either store them in some other class with a `static` modifier, or use `SharedPreferences` or some database.

Comment: I need to read what is SharedPreferences.... but for database it's not ok.
I have to save little data, i use serialized files.
But before make a file a need to create the list of materials.
Thanks

Comment: Then `SharedPreferenced` are specifically here to save small amount of key values. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html